# Is it possible to show uppercase text in an input box but the user copies the lowercase form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input text box whose value is defined by a javascript function. I would like it to display the text in all uppercase. When the user copies the text, is it possible that they copy the all lowercase form?

Possible ideas are changing the text box value back to lowercase on click .

The reason I want to do this is that users are copying a case sensitive code but it is much easier to read in uppercase.

```
<input style="text-transform:uppercase" type="text" value="hello" />
```

Comment: imo,  I would be temped to copy what they see on the screen. It will be confusing otherwise. i.e. they copy and paste but get something they don't expect. They may not like it but at least the behavior is consistent? And if it is supposed to be formatted uppercase then when they paste it into other fields, it will be unchanged and be correct.

Comment: If the code is case sensitive, you'd be doing your users a disservice by displaying it in the wrong case, even if you correct it in the clipboard.  If it's difficult to read, perhaps a different font choice is in order.

Comment: @DanielBeck You're probably right. To give context, it is a discount voucher code. I don't think it needs to be case sensitive on the devices I have tested. This is reduced back to lower case as a precaution if a user decides to copy and paste the voucher code. If not copying the text, I think most people won't bother with entering the voucher code in all caps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out by raising the original javascript variable to uppercase and then sending it to the input box. Once clicked, a function will lower the case of the text.

For my case, I also wanted the text input field to highlight all the text so it can easily be copied. But this caused issues as each time the user would click to highlight, the function to lower the text case is called again. I hence added a counter so it only operates the function once.

It wasn't working in jfiddle so here's another link to play with: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FELVWXFTQHZQ

HTML:

```
    <input id="inputBox" onclick="lwrCase(); this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" spellcheck="false" type="text" value="Loading..." />
```

Javascript:

```
// Variable to send
var myVariable = "StackOverflow";

// Send variable in uppercase form to input box
document.getElementById('inputBox').value = myVariable.toUpperCase();

// Variable to indicate state
var lowered = 0;

// Function to restore string to original variable
function lwrCase() {
    if (lowered == 0){
        document.getElementById('inputBox').value = myVariable;
    }
    // Increase counter to indicate the string is restored
    lowered = lowered + 1;
}
```

Confirmed working on latest versions of following browsers:

```
• Windows/Mac: Chrome, FireFox, Internet Explorer, Edge, Safari
• Android: Chrome
• iOS9: Safari, Chrome
• iOS6: Safari
• Windows Phone 8.1: Default browser
```

Answer (score 0):

The style only affects the presentation. Therefore the value is lowercase when it is submitted or copied.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case in the browsers I have tested.

See https://jsfiddle.net/a0nmqyrh/

Comment: On copy (to clipboard), not all the browsers: Firefox works fine, Chrome not.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
input:active {
  text-transform: none;
}
```

### Edit:

**HTML**

```
<input id="input" onkeydown="keyDown()" onkeyup="keyUp()">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function keyDown() {
  document.getElementById('input').style.textTransform = "none";
}
function keyUp() {
  document.getElementById('input').style.textTransform = "uppercase";
}
```

### Edit 2

**HTML**

```
<input id="input" onclick="toggle()">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function toggle() {
  if (document.getElementById('input').style.textTransform == "none") document.getElementById('input').style.textTransform = "uppercase";
  else document.getElementById('input').style.textTransform = "none";
}
```

Comment: `:active` is in effect between mousedown and mouseup.  That doesn't really help with ctrl-C...

Comment: Well htr5 asked for onclick not that. You could still be holding down from selecting while ctrl+c by the way

Comment: Thanks. This works in raising the case of the input. But I was after an onclick. The input box only purpose is to make it easier to copy the text on all devices.